# How to perform operations in a delete participant before delete project contents on disk is done in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I created a plugin which has a delete participant. The delete participant deletes the reference to the project in a versioning tool.

For deleting the reference I need some data which I collect from the project files.

The problem appears when the user checks the "Delete project contents on disk".

The content on disk is deleted after my participant creates a Change.

How to retrieve data that has to be used for deleting the reference before the project is deleted from disk ?

**EDIT**

I can retrieve the data when the change is created but due to some environment circumstances I need to have the project on disk when I try to delete the reference of the project.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. If the content is deleted after your Change is created why can't you just get the information when you create the Change?

Comment: The problem arises when I actually want delete to the reference. In order to delete the reference, the versioning system reads a file that doesn't exist anymore at the time when the change is executed. If I add the deleting of the reference when I create the change, everytime when the user uses  preview, the plugin will try to delete the reference. I need to delete the reference just when user chooses to delete the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `createPreChange` method of `DeleteParticipant` to create a `Change` which is run before the main change list.

Comment: That was, thanks, I forgot to look in the DeleteParticipant, which I extended